# MySQL won't start

Tags: mysql

```
110926 12:09:41  InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percents: 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 3329, file name /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.004279
110926 12:09:42  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 46 4210009908
110926 12:09:42 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin
110926 12:09:42 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
110926 12:09:42 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
110926 12:09:42 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.0.45-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

from web admin:

```
#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)
```

Every time I access the DB, it crashes as far as I can tell

Comment: more log output: looks like I/O error:

Comment: Version: '5.0.45-log'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
InnoDB: Error: tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 2 64110592.
InnoDB: Was only able to read -1.
110926 12:14:39  InnoDB: Operating system error number 5 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 5 means 'Input/output error'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: File operation call: 'read'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.

Comment: Problem was HDD:
`test`

`    === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
    SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
    Please note the following marginal Attributes:
    ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE         UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
    190 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   045   032   045    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 55`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL was failing to read parts of the database due to a failing HDD.

mysqldump would fail because of this as well.

I ended up writing a python script to pull out all the readable parts of the Innodb database.

In summary:

1. img'd hard drive with dd (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/dd-command-examples/)
2. backed up database via mysqldump (with python script to skip unreadables)
3. imported into new system

Comment: p.s. I tested the HDD via http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-if-harddisk-failing.html

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you say, have you tried to do a FORCED FULL fsck of the disk where the database information resides?

Answer (score -3):

Restart webmin after you restart MySQL. Depending on your distribution it could be

```
service webin restart
```

or

```
/ect/init.d/webin restart
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: My thoughts exactly, @JohnGardeniers. Hence the downvote...

Comment: Good question. I must have had some other question in my mind. My bad.

Comment: Actually, I take it back. He's getting errors from webmin as well as MySQL. My thought is that once he restarts MySQL he should also restart Webmin. So, while it may not work, it is a valid answer that addresses the problem.